# Using foreign keys to limit values allowed in a field based on values in another field

Tags: sql, database

I have a database table whose records are "sales", with one of the fields being "Country" (where the sale occurred).

I want to make sure people can only enter a valid country name (e.g., Republic of Korea vs South Korea). I can't do this with a CHECK constraint since it's not a fixed value check or based on another value in the row.

However, I do think it's a good candidate for using a foreign key constraint:

1. Create a new table 'countries' where the country name is the primary key (we could also include other fields like 'population', 'currency_code' etc if we wanted, but that is tangential to my question).
2. Make the "Country" field in my 'sales' table a foreign key, with reference to the "country_name" primary key in "countries" table.

This would not only enforce consistent naming (or presentation of a pick-list if using a UI) but also further normalize our data (now country-level data can be stored in one place).

Is there another way to enforce these type of 'pick-list' constraints, where the pick list can be dynamic (based on another table that may be updated)?

My only concern with my approach is that if we change a country name, we could wreak havoc with the sales table. Maybe a better approach is to change the field in "sales" from "country" to "country_id" and then create a UUID for each country in the country table. This way, the user could still look up which id they want to use (again, perhaps via a graphical pick list) but we won't break the tables if we re-name the country.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that having a separate Country table would be the more normalized and flexible approach, but a field whose value may potentially change is never a good candidate to be a primary key -- that's usually a red flag that you've chosen the wrong field for your primary key.

A hybrid approach is for your Country table's primary key could be something like a "CountryCode" or "CountryIdentifier", which could be a small character field that could hold an abbreviation or shortened name that you use like an identifier, use that same value as your foreign key in your Sales table.  Then the full Country name could be one of the additional fields you normalize in the Country table, which could change when necessary, and could be displayed in your UI, but if you ever needed to look at your data directly, you have something a little more readable that an number or UUID.

Comment: Good suggestions! Thanks!